# Wave: Unable to delete a dashboard with a missing dataset

Tags: json, dashboard, einstein-analytics, data-set

I erased the current datasets(deleted the json) and created new ones. However I cannot delete the dashboards associated with the previous datasets at this point. Any ideas how can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to view your dashboard and if you tack on /json to the end of your dashboard URL, it will let you go into the dashboard json and edit/save.